# Link to Controller does not work within pdf 0.6

Tags: pdf, grails, controller, call

i'm programming with Groovy&Grails a portal, to show different pdf-pages. In one case i need to show an image from an database inside a pdf.

For the pdf creation i use pdf 0.6

The plugin generates the pdf, but the image in the .gsp, wont be displayed:

```
<img style="height: 100px; float: right;" src="${grailsApplication.config.grails.tomcatURL}${createLinkTo(controller: 'mandant', action: 'logo_image', id: mandant.id)}"
```

The .gsp ingnores that call to controller, cause i have some println's in the method so i can be sure that the .gsp don't call it.

If i put that g-string:

`${grailsApplication.config.grails.tomcatURL}${createLinkTo(controller: 'mandant', action: 'logo_image', id: mandant.id)}`

without the `<img-tag>` in the gsp, and klicked on that hyperlink, the gsp calls the controller and the image is displayed in a new browser tab.

I hope that anyone understand my problem

Greetz

Max Jando

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use the `base` property (and the `createLink` [tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html)) like:

```
${createLink(controller: 'mandant', action: 'logo_image', id: mandant.id, base:grailsApplication.config.grails.tomcatURL)}
```

Comment: Hi tim_yates, this does not work. PDF had no Image.
By the way: If i skip the pdf generation and let show the html page , the image appears.

Comment: Yes it does. If insert the tag out of an <img> - Tag the link is correct

Comment: can you use firebug or chrome developer tools to inspect the request/response from the server for that image element?  Is it giving you a 404 error?  Or invalid content?  You're missing the `/>` off the end of your tag in the question, but I assume that's just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: the end-tag "/>" is not missing. how do i recieve a response from server in case of a pdf? i could skip the pdf generation, but in that case i have no problem. The Image in the Pdf doesn't appear, just blank and no error appear.

Comment: i think that the gsp cannot open the controller, but i dont know why